# Compilation error for matrix log using Eigen in 12.04

Tags: ros, eigen, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, eigen3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I've written, compiled, and run the following code on my personal machine that runs 13.04:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/MatrixFunctions>
#include <ur5/utilities.h>
#include <me530646_lab1/lab1.h>
#include <me530646_lab2/lab2.h>
#include <me530646_lab3/lab3.h>
#include <me530646_lab4/lab4.h>

#define PI M_PI

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    ros::init(argc,argv,"lab3");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    UR5 robot = UR5(n);

    //Example of how to use the matrix logarithm
    Eigen::Vector3d v(0,0,PI/4);
    printf("Vector v:\n");
    printEigen(v);
    Eigen::Matrix3d R =  expr(v);
    printf("expr(v)\n");
    printEigen(R);
    Eigen::Matrix3d skew = R.log();
    printf("expr(v).log()\n");
    printEigen(skew);
    printf("\"Unskew\"  of expr(v).log():\n");
    printEigen(Eigen::Vector3f(skew(2,1),skew(0,2),skew(1,0)));

}
```

When I try to run it on a machine with 12.04, however, I get the following error:

```
/home/rkeatin3/ur5_ws/src/me530646/ME530646/me530646_project/src/project_main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/rkeatin3/ur5_ws/src/me530646/ME530646/me530646_project/src/project_main.cpp:68:49: error: ‘const Type’ has no member named ‘log’
make[2]: *** [me530646/ME530646/me530646_project/CMakeFiles/project_main.dir/src/project_main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [me530646/ME530646/me530646_project/CMakeFiles/project_main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

What's causing this problem, and how do I fix it? I tried downloading the most recent version and copying the header files to /usr/include, but that didn't fix the problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199126/compilation-error-for-matrix-log-using-eigen-in-12.04/) by [rkeatin3](https://answers.ros.org/users/19735/rkeatin3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2014-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this problem by doing the following:

1. Download this file: [http://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/3.2.2.tar.gz](Download this file: http://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/3.2.2.tar.gz)
2. cd into `~/Downloads`
3. Extract the zip file with `tar xvzf eigen-eigen-1306d75b4a21.tar.gz`
4. Copy the files to the correct location with `sudo cp -r eigen-eigen-1306d75b4a21/ /usr/include/eigen3`

I believe what I tried before didn't work because I copied the files incorrectly.

---

Originally posted by [rkeatin3](https://answers.ros.org/users/19735/rkeatin3/) with karma: 156 on 2014-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0